# How to use Bootstrap collapse dynamically in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap collapse with ASP.NET C#. I want to print data from database in collapse format.

Database:

```
Course_id | Course_Name | Course_Category
1         | MS Word     | Computer Course
2         | MS Excel    | Computer Course
3         | MS Powepoint| Computer Course
4         | VMWARE      | Computer Course
5         | PHP         | Computer Course
6         | ASP.NET     | Computer Course
7         | Auditing    | Accounts
8         | Accounts    | Accounts
9         | Tally       | Accounts
10        | Assets      | Accounts
```

I Want to show it like this using bootstrap collapse.

Computer Course:

- MS Word
- MS Excel
- MS Powepoint
- VMWARE
- PHP
- ASP.NET

Accounts:

- Auditing
- Accounts
- Tally
- Assets

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></a>
                                </h4>
                                </div>
                            <div id="collapse<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="list-group">
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a class="list-group-item" href="StudentCourseDetails.aspx?C=<%# Eval("Course") %>"><%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %> <%# Eval("Course_Name") %></a>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void GetCourses()
{
    DT = BLL.GetDistinctCourseName();
    if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Repeater2.DataSource = DT;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
        for (int a = 0; a < DT.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            Literal Literal1 = Repeater2.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("Literal1") as Literal;
            Literal1.Text = DT.Rows[a]["Course_Cat"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```